# Why does Composer say "Conclusion: don't install" when (seemingly) no obstacles are present?

Tags: composer-php

The following `composer.json`:

```
{
    "type": "project",
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "require": {
        "jasny/bootstrap": ">=3.1.3",
        "2amigos/yii2-file-input-widget": "*"
    }
}
```

leads to the following output of `composer update`:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.                               

  Problem 1
    - 2amigos/yii2-file-input-widget 0.1.2 requires jasny/bootstrap v3.1.0 -> satisfiable by jasny/bootstrap[v3.1.0] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - 2amigos/yii2-file-input-widget 0.1.1 requires jasny/bootstrap v3.1.0 -> satisfiable by jasny/bootstrap[v3.1.0] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - 2amigos/yii2-file-input-widget 0.1.0 requires jasny/bootstrap v3.1.0 -> satisfiable by jasny/bootstrap[v3.1.0] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - 2amigos/yii2-file-input-widget 1.0.0 requires jasny/bootstrap ~3.1.0 -> satisfiable by jasny/bootstrap[v3.1.3].
    - 2amigos/yii2-file-input-widget 1.0.1 requires jasny/bootstrap ~3.1.0 -> satisfiable by jasny/bootstrap[v3.1.3].
    - 2amigos/yii2-file-input-widget 1.0.2 requires jasny/bootstrap ~3.1.0 -> satisfiable by jasny/bootstrap[v3.1.3].
    - 2amigos/yii2-file-input-widget dev-master requires jasny/bootstrap ~3.1.0 -> satisfiable by jasny/bootstrap[v3.1.3].
    - 2amigos/yii2-file-input-widget 1.0.x-dev requires jasny/bootstrap ~3.1.0 -> satisfiable by jasny/bootstrap[v3.1.3].
    - Conclusion: don't install jasny/bootstrap v3.1.3
    - Installation request for 2amigos/yii2-file-input-widget * -> satisfiable by 2amigos/yii2-file-input-widget[0.1.0, 0.1.1, 0.1.2, 1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.2, dev-master, 1.0.x-dev].
```

Why?

---

Ok, I understand, why versions `0.1.0–0.1.2` of `2amigos/yii2-file-input-widget` can't be installed — because they require `jasny/bootstrap` of exact version `3.1.0`, which conflicts with `>=3.1.3` requirement in `composer.json` (and therefore composer clarifies: `but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability`).

But, from common-sense view, composer can install version 1.0.0 or later of `2amigos/yii2-file-input-widget` (which requires `jasny/bootstrap` of version `~3.1.0`, which is satisfiable by 3.1.3). Neither I see any obstacles for installing `2amigos/yii2-file-input-widget` 1.0.0+ together with `jasny/bootstrap` 3.1.3, nor composer writes any explicit clarification about it. Still it says: `Conclusion: don't install jasny/bootstrap v3.1.3` — why?

#### Workaround 1

It seems it works with `"prefer-stable": true`.

#### Workaround 2

I actually found the other workaround some time ago: I replace `"2amigos/yii2-file-input-widget": "*"` with `"2amigos/yii2-file-input-widget": "1.0.2"`, do `composer update` and then replace it back and do `composer update` again — and it works.

---

The question is why it works in so strange way: why it works with more restrictions, but fails with less restrictions (with no clarification). E.g. if it works with `1.0.2` (or with prefer-stable) works — then why it doesn't with `*` (or without prefer-stable)?

Comment: Can you show your `composer.json`?

Comment: @localheinz, excerpt from `require` section from `composed.json` is in the beginning of the question. Do some other sections matter?

Comment: Have you tried adding `"prefer-stable": true` to `composer.json`? See https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#prefer-stable.

Comment: @localheinz, yes, it works with `"prefer-stable": true`. I actually found the other workaround some time ago: I replace `"2amigos/yii2-file-input-widget": "*"` with `"2amigos/yii2-file-input-widget": "1.0.2"`, do `composer update` and then replace it back and do `composer update` again — and it works. The question is **why** it works in so strange way: why it works with more restrictions, but fails with less restrictions (with no clarification). E.g. if it works with `"1.0.2"` (or with prefer-stable) works — then why it doesn't with `"*"` (or without prefer-stable)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the order and it should work, e.g.

```
{
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "require": {
        "2amigos/yii2-file-input-widget": "*",
        "jasny/bootstrap": ">=3.1.3"
    }
}
```

Why? I don't know. Most likely a Composer's bug.

I've tested two configurations with different order on the empty folder using `composer install` command (Composer v1.6.3), the original order fails, however the order above works. I've reported the issue at [GH-7215](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/7215).

Comment: Thanks. I've actually found a similar report right now: [5780](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/5780). But it was incomplete at the time of its creation and therefore closed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might well be that you are manually editing `composer.json` and then running

```
$ composer update
```

Instead, revert the changes to `composer.json` and then run:

```
$ composer require jasny/bootstrap:>=3.1.3
$ composer require "2amigos/yii2-file-input-widget:*"
```

or in one go:

```
$ composer require jasny/bootstrap:>=3.1.3 "2amigos/yii2-file-input-widget:*"
```

**Note** I recommend to avoid the `*` wildcard as version constraint because it could pull in any version of that dependency, and potentially break your application by pulling in a version that is not compatible with it.

For reference, see:

- http://semver.org

Comment: Fails with same error message. BTW, when I run `composer require "jasny/bootstrap:>=3.1.3" "2amigos/yii2-file-input-widget:*"`, it somewhy adds `"2amigos/yii2-file-input-widget" : "1.0.x-dev"` (not `"2amigos/yii2-file-input-widget" : "*"`) into the `composer.json` (but then restores `composer.json`, as command failed).